# Output JSON messages with Debezium rather than Avro

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Is it possible to generate JSON messages with Debezium rather than Avro? I have a Debezium Kafka Connect adapter and I'm trying to get it to output JSON messages into the Kafka topic.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want JSON messages in the Kafka topic?

Comment: I'm using a library (Faust), which I don't think can use Avro messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add these to get JSON output

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```